# Constraints / Foreign keys information in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have to get the Table and Column name of the Foreign keys on Oracle, can anybody confirm the following statement?

```
SELECT a.table_name AS TableWithForeignKey, b.column_name AS ForeignKeyColumn 
FROM user_constraints a INNER JOIN user_cons_columns b 
ON (a.constraint_name = b.constraint_name) AND (a.table_name = b.table_name)
and a.constraint_type = 'R'
```

The Part I'm not sure about is the INNER JOIN Part (after ON):

```
(a.constraint_name = b.constraint_name) AND (a.table_name = b.table_name)
```

As I couldn't find something like constraints_ID, is this enought to match 1:1 rows from both tables **user_constraints** and **user_cons_columns**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the

```
a.constraint_name = b.constraint_name
```

for joining the 2 views
so, I think it's OK

Comment: I had it like this at the begining but i was not really sure the constraint_name is unique, thats why i combined htis with the table name. do you know for sure that its unique?

Comment: You can't have duplicate constraint names for a given user. Since the query is on user_constraints and user_cons_columns, you don't need to worry about duplicate names. If you were querying all_constraints, then it could be important.